# When did we first learn that Jupiter was a gas giant?

Tags: astronomy

The term "gas giant" was invented in the 1950s, but I think the concept has been known longer than that.

When did we first learn that Jupiter was a gas giant, not a terrestrial-type planet?

Answer (score 8):

We need to clear one thing up here, and that is the definition of a gas giant. As an example, take [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_giant):

> A gas giant is a giant planet composed mainly of hydrogen and helium.

All we have to do to classify Jupiter as a gas giant is to prove that it's made of . . . gas.

The answer leads to [Giovanni Cassini](http://www.space.com/18902-giovanni-cassini.html), who observed Jupiter's [differential rotation](http://www.space.com/18902-giovanni-cassini.html) in the 1690s, thus showing that it could not be solid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've clarified the question a bit, hopefully getting rid of the ambiguity you described.  (Though I'm not so sure Cassini was doing much research in the 1960s.)

Comment: @Joe Ack! Typo. I also edited out the now irrelevant stuff.